# Prevent remote runs on TeamCity?

Tags: maven-2, teamcity

Is there a way to configure a TeamCity build to forbid remote runs? I want to configure a maven build that deploys a snapshot but I don't want to allow remote runs on that configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I found a work-around that lets me prevent deploying jars from a remote run.

```
<properties>
    <!-- this setting is needed for TeamCity -->
    <maven.deploy.skip>${build.is.personal}</maven.deploy.skip>
</properties>
```

I would still prefer to forbid the remote run entirely if there is a way. It's wasteful to run the "deploy" configuration and there are other configurations I'd like to forbid as well.